# Consume async iterable without variable declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, generator, es6-promise

With a synchronous JavaScript generator I can iterate over it as follows:

```js
(() => {
  function * syncGenerator () {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    console.log('done')
  }

  Array.from(syncGenerator())
})()
```

This will simply iterate over the whole generator without having to initialise a variable. I would like to do the same with async generators. The closest solution I could come up with is as follows:

```js
(async () => {
  async function * asyncGenerator () {
    yield Promise.resolve(1)
    yield Promise.resolve(2)
    yield Promise.resolve(3)
    console.log('done')
  }

  for await (const num of asyncGenerator()) {}
})()
```

Unfortunately I had to instantiate the variable `num` in the above code snippet. This causes StandardJS to give an error on that line, because the variable isn't used. Is there any way I can iterate over an async generator without having to create a variable?

Comment: This may be a bit XY-ish; why does StandardJS have a problem with the existence of a variable?

Comment: The [*iterator helpers* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) will have a `toArray` method

Comment: If the promises need to be built and resolve in sequence, use `.then()`. If order doesn't matter, use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, that's a good tip. Those helpers would solve my problem elegantly.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk StandardJS complains that the variable is initialised, but not used. I will update my question for clarity.

Comment: @Ouroborus Using `Promise.all()` would be ideal. But I can't think of a quick, elegant way to do it. I tried `Promise.all(Array.from(asyncGenerator()))`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like there's no async generator comprehension. Alternatively, StandardJS does offer a way to [hide certain warnings](https://standardjs.com/#how-do-i-hide-a-certain-warning).

Answer (score 1):

## Current solution

Based on the comments to the question and my own research my preferred solution to the problem at the time of writing is the following:

```js
(async () => {
  async function * asyncGenerator () {
    yield Promise.resolve(1)
    yield Promise.resolve(2)
    yield Promise.resolve(3)
    console.log('done')
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  for await (const num of asyncGenerator()) {}
})()
```

Note the `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` comment which suppresses the warning generated by StandardJS for that one line.

## Future solution

Once the [Iterator Helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) proposal matures and becomes available one could do something like the following for both synchronous and asynchronous generators:

```js
function * syncGenerator () {
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
  console.log('sync done')
}

syncGenerator().forEach(() => {}) // Logs 'sync done'

async function * asyncGenerator () {
  yield Promise.resolve(1)
  yield Promise.resolve(2)
  yield Promise.resolve(3)
  console.log('async done')
}

asyncGenerator().forEach(() => {}) // Logs 'async done'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method

```
    async function * asyncGenerator(): AsyncIterableIterator<number> {
        yield Promise.resolve(1)
        yield Promise.resolve(2)
        yield Promise.resolve(3)
        console.log('async done')
    }
    const it: AsyncIterableIterator<number> = asyncGenerator()
    while (true) {
        const result: IteratorResult<number> = await it.next();
        if (result.done) break;
    }
```

(TypeScript types added for documentation purposes)

Of course, this does declare the variable `it`, but it's not unused, which I believe is what your actual problem was.

That said, my ESLint did complain about the use of `while (true)` (with config `eslint:recommended`), which I personally find a bit stupid, but may or may not be a problem for you.